# Need to know which namespace and class are loaded when I do require in PHP

Tags: php, reflection

Basically I just want to require "some.class.php"; and know what class is inside that file.

The answer is:

Get the last value of the function `get_declared_classes`

Comment: I'm sorry this is not about namespaces ... so you shouldn't really mark it as duplicate it has nothing to do with namespaces.

Comment: Agreed, have requested a reopen. However you do need to explain your question better. php5 does have reflection http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php

Comment: I've also cast a reopen vote, but you should really remove the "yelling" from your most recent edit, and just clarify the question a little further.

Comment: I know I just hate automatons, reminds me of IRC OPs

Comment: Your initial question was very hard to understand; jumping to the conclusion that it is something about namespaces was not completely unwarranted. Alternatively I'd have closed it as *Unclear*. No reason to misbehave, just clarify what exactly you're asking instead.

Comment: BTW, if you have an answer, go ahead and post it as answer; not within the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
   require "Some.class.php";

   $loadedClasses = get_declared_classes();
   $lastClass     = array_pop($loadedClasses);

   echo "Last loaded class is $lastClass";
```

Comment: Note that there's absolutely no guarantee as far as I'm aware that `get_declared_classes` will always return classes in the order they were loaded. It is also possible that the file you `require` loads more classes itself.

Comment: Well I just want to know the LAST class so if it requires files inside it's fine by me.